# 50% width block layout isn't spacing properly, Not sure why

Tags: php, html, css

I applied a custom container to a WordPress Categories template file, set the width to 50%, floated it left, but after the third instance occurs, the layout breaks from what is expected.

I've tried changing the display types, checked for re-occurrence on other browsers(It occurs in both Chrome and Mozilla Firefox). I've also tried applying a clearfix to the container.

```
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.category .post-block {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
    float: left;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTBUO.jpg (Not enough rep for posting images directly yet)

The location of the problem observed:

https://streamershaven.blog/category/hardware/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using the flexbox model outlined https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Have a fallback for no browser support in place.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider padding, margin and border as part of total element width.

"content-box" box model:

"Total element width = width + left padding + right padding + left border + right border + left margin + right margin"

[The CSS Box Model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Comment: I actually solved the issue by switching to the flexbox model. Not fully supported, but not a big deal. The fallback is simply 100% width units.

I also removed the padding on all the elements before trying the flexbox model, didn't work.